# user sees DATE in other language

Tags: microsoft-word, language, documents

I have a MS Word .doc document and it has a DATE field. I have a not English location on my computer and when I open the document then I see the DATE field in English formatting, and this is correct. But the other guy sees it in other language, which is incorrect. How can I fix it? I've tried adding \l key, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. display the field code (e.g. using Alt-F9)

b. select the field code

c. use Tools->Language to format it explicitly as English